# Matlab Image Translation: Index Exceeds Matrix Dimensions

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, indexing, translate

I have been trying to translate images throughout an image sequence by specifying a common location on key frames and interpolate based on those points.  Seems pretty simple, but I've been getting an error even though the images seem to be translating just fine.  This is annoying since it works but I can't put anything more in my code because of the error which is "`??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`" on the line, `for k=pos{j-1}(1):pos{j}(1)` and I cant seem to figure out why.  I have R2011a 32-bit.  Thanks for the help! Here is my code:

```
% // numkeyframes=input('Enter the number of key frames');
pos=cell(1,3);
for i=1:numkeyframes
pos{i}=input('Enter frame, x position, and y position in format "[f x y]"');
end

D=dir('*.bmp');
imcell=cell(1,numel(D));
for i=1:numel(D)
imcell{i}=imread(D(i).name,'bmp');
end

for j=2:pos{numkeyframes}(1)
for k=pos{j-1}(1):pos{j}(1)
xdisp=round((pos{1}(2)-pos{j}(2))*(k-pos{j-1}(1))/(pos{j}(1)-pos{j-1}(1)));
ydisp=round((pos{1}(3)-pos{j}(3))*(k-pos{j-1}(1))/(pos{j}(1)-pos{j-1}(1)));
structelem=translate(strel(1),[xdisp,ydisp]);
imtrans{k}=imdilate(imcell{k},structelem);
end
end
```

Comment: Seems like you want `for j=2:numel(pos)`, but the problem seems to depend on the input.

Comment: `dbstop if error` and check at what value of `j` it errors.  Compare that to the size of `pos`.